# NFL teams with back to back shutouts

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, history

St. Louis Rams beat the Oakland Raiders in week 13 (of 2014 season) by a score of 52 to 0, and went on to beat Washington Redskins the following week 24 - 0.
Are the Rams the first team to win back to back games without allowing their opponents to  score any points? If not, what other teams accomplished this feat; and what is the longest streak of holding your opponents to no points in the NFL?

Comment: How many point were racked up by the three game winners before the opponents in the fourth game put points on the board ?

Comment: Please post your comment to the answer below since I do not no about the three game winning streak. @paveoverflow who provided the answer does!

Comment: @alamoot note that the user has less than [50 reputation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (it was originally an answer converted to a comment...one you commented on yourself).

Comment: @edmastermind29 I know that, I just want to make sure that this new users learns about our conventions and proper way of using the sire, that's all!

Comment: @alamoot Understood. Thanks for taking the time to do so!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [Wikipedia list of NFL records by team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Football_League_records_(team)), the "Most Consecutive Shutout Games Won or Tied" was 13 by the Akron Pros over the 1920 and 1921 seasons.  They finished the [1920 season](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_Akron_Pros_season#Schedule) with 5 straight shutouts (the last 2 were ties), and they started the [1921 season](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1921_Akron_Pros_season) with 8 straight shutouts (the last one was a tie).

But the most consecutive shutouts in the modern era is three.  This was accomplished by the [1970 St.Louis Cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_St._Louis_Cardinals_%28NFL%29_season) (3 straight shutout wins) and the 1976-77 Steelers (they had 3 straight shutout wins in the [middle of the season](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1976_Pittsburgh_Steelers_season#Schedule), and also had 2 straight shutout wins at the end of the regular season and a shutout win in [week 1 of the 1977 season](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1977_Pittsburgh_Steelers_season#Schedule)).  A [philly.com article](http://www.philly.com/philly/blogs/sports/eagles/Blankety-Blank-1024.html) mentions this:

> The only NFL teams (since 1940) to have three consecutive shutouts were the 1970 Cardinals and the Steelers, who did it during Games 7-8-9 of the 1976 season and closed out that season with a pair (Games 13-14) and started 1977 with one (Game 1).

Comment: Yep, the era is important.  In the early days, shutouts were very common, as were 0-0 ties.  Lower skill level combined with no passing game meant for a very low scoring game (which apparently people were more apt to watch back then in the US than they are to watch soccer 0-0 ties now?)

Answer (score 2):

In modern NFL football, this would be the Miami Dolphins, who shutout the Baltimore Colts 4 consecutive times, from January 2, 1972 (AFC Championship) to November 11, 1973. 
The cumulative score of all four games was 104-0.